# scroll elements down in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm building a basic forum where each post contains a name, a message and a date.
The forum is written in PHP and updates with AJAX to load new posts on the fly.
When new posts come in, I would like the old posts to ease down nicely (much like facebook does today when you have new updates) and to make room for the new posts.
Can anyone point me in the direction of how to go about something like this?

Comment: What part do you want to know? The AJAX part or the slide down part?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very stupid example but...

Say you have a page with a button `id="foo"`

and a style sheet with:  `.bar{display: none;}`

Then this js:

```
$("#foo").click(function(){

        $(this).before("<div class='bar'><p>HELLO!</p><br /><p>WORLD!</p><div>");
        $(".bar:first").slideDown("slow");

});
```

This should give the effect you're looking for.

Comment: let me know if this doesn't help.